# Sum two values after Union of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, union

this is my query:

```
SELECT location_description as Crimes,COUNT(*)
FROM test_sample
where test_sample.day_of_week LIKE"%sunday"
GROUP BY test_sample.location_description
UNION ALL
SELECT location_description as Crimes,COUNT(*)
FROM test_sample
where test_sample.day_of_week LIKE"%saturday"
GROUP BY test_sample.location_description
```

My output is:
[image]

How can i merge this two duplicate values into one.

Answer (score 3):

If you need get count of records only by 'location_description' field than you can use only grouping without union

```
SELECT location_description AS Crimes,
       COUNT(*)
FROM test_sample
WHERE day_of_week LIKE "%sunday"
  OR day_of_week LIKE "%saturday"
GROUP BY location_description
```

Comment: You type faster than me! But you forgot to add an explanation. +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I was added the little explanation

Comment: Thanks alot.. I don't know i was making my problem more complex..Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

No need to `UNION` now, simply adjust `WHERE` to include both days;

```
SELECT location_description as Crimes,COUNT(*)
FROM test_sample
where test_sample.day_of_week LIKE"%sunday"
   or test_sample.day_of_week LIKE"%saturday"
GROUP BY test_sample.location_description
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. I don't know i was making my problem more complex..Thank you :)